# cross correlation using fft producing inaccurate results

Tags: r, fft, cross-correlation

I tried posting this question last week, but since it wasn't answered I decided to rewrite the question with a simpler, more direct format.

I am using r to compute the cross correlation between two timeseries. As an example, I am taking the two timeseries, which are just sin waves lagged slightly:

```
x = rnorm(100)
y = rnorm(100)
#x = (x - mean(x))/sd(x) 
#y = (y-mean(y))/sd(y)
zeroPad = rep(0,200)
x0 = zeroPad    
y0 = zeroPad
x0[1:100] = x
y0[1:100] = y


ccf = ccf(x,y,lag.max = 100,plot=F)
ccf = ccf$acf
ccf2 = 2*Re(fft((1/length(x0))*fft(x0)*(1/length(x0))*fft(rev(y0)),inverse  =T))
ccf2 = c(ccf2[(length(ccf2)-length(x)+1):length(ccf2)],ccf2[1:length(x)])

plot(ccf,type="l")
lines(ccf2,col=2)
```

According to this post: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/736/how-do-i-implement-cross-correlation-to-prove-two-audio-files-are-similar 
and sevreral others, the outputs ccf1 and ccf2 should be the same: one of them is computed the normal way in the time domain, and the other is computed as a convolution in the frequency domain. However, The output I am getting looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know why there is this error/discrepancy? In certain cases it is much worse -- this was just an easily reproducible example.

Comment: Could you add a `set.seed()` to your example? Every time I try your code, results are very similar.

Comment: @Pascal, thank you for pointing this out. I definitely ran this script before and it produced not only the above error but much worse error. But now I am also noticing that the error isn't there anymore. I will try to find out what changed -- perhaps it was my environment. I will try inputting several more, stranger functions into x and y and see if I can reproduce the error again.

Comment: So it turns out that the innaccuracy was coming from the fact that I was not in fact normalizing the series before passing them to the cross correlation functions. (I have updated my code to reflect this fact). While rnorm should produce mean 0, variance 1 observations, if it is slightly off that will produce the slight error I described. Just FYI, the original error I had was because I was sometimes truncating one of the timeseries after normalizing and de-meaning it, which was throwing off the normalization process.